# How to compare string date + month with current date + month

Tags: android, date, date-comparison

**What I want to do:**

> I have a `TextView` where I want to show a quote whole year each day
>   with new quote.

**Details:**

For that I want to compare **current date+month** with the given **string date+month** only.
Given date format will be **dd-MM** (I don't want the current year)

How can I compare dates?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
"18-03-2017".substring(0, 5);
```

Will return "18-03" as it takes a substring from index 0 to index 5 (remember that it actually goes from 0 to 4 because of indexing behaviour).

So if you have a date stored in a variable called "date" it would be just like this:

```
date.substring(0, 5);
```

And if you want to store that new date in a variable, it would be like this:

```
var = date.substring(0, 5);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ignacia Valdes Zamudio appreciate your reply. I have tried to get your answer but unfortunately could not solve it as I am new in android. I want you to please give proper snippet as in below ans by Pete.

Comment: Can you please also find the problem with @Pete answer given below. This snippet works perfectly but the problem is it works only on API 24/25 only, it does not support any other API below 24 and gives red line (error) under the object **SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ()** can you please tell me how to solve this error or any other alternative ???

Comment: I will be able to help you if you edit your original post and add your code. If I don't know the name of your variables or how you manage the dates, I won't be able to say more than what I said. I encourage you to edit your post and add your code ;)

Comment: @Ignacia Valdes Zamudio thanks I have pasted my code below the page kindly check it out

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like:

```
​import java.text.*

String dateStr = "18-03"
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM")​​​​​​
​Date currentDate = new Date()


if( dateStr.equals(sdf.format(currentDate)) ){
    System.out.println("dates are the same")
}else{
    System.out.println("dates are different!")
}
```

So just use the SimpleDateFormat class to format the date to a string that only has date and month and compare that with the string of a date you have
    ​

Comment: thanx for your code which works but this snippet works only on API 24/25. It does not supports below than API 24. As a red line(error) show under the object of  **SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");** which shows this message **Call requires API level 24 (current min is 23): android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat#SimpleDateFormat less... (Ctrl+F1)** Can you please help out how to deal with lower APIs.

Comment: can you please give me any suggestion why  `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");` is not supported below API 24 or how can we make it supported below from API 24,

Comment: Try to use the SimpleDateFormat class from the Java platform, not from android https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
So currently your class probably has an import for android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat, change that to java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

@Ignacia Valdes Zamudio this is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

quote = new String("The Quote under else block is showing");
mtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    String datestr = "19-03";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
            Date currentDate = new Date();

    if (datestr.equals(sdf.format(currentDate))) {
        mtv.setText("today date is 18 of march");
    }

    else {

        mtv.setText(quote);
    }
```

Error show me at this line.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
```

Android Studio says that this class is not be support below API 24. MESSAGE SHOWN BY STUDIO **call requires API level 24 (current min is 23): android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat#SimpleDateFormat less... (Ctrl+F1) **